# how to overcome scala NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

just getting started with scala and spark
trying to run this simple program:

```
package spark.example

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkGrep {
  def main(args: Array[String] = Array("default argument")) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkGrep").setMaster("localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val inputFile = sc.textFile("/Users/eugene/Downloads/hello.txt").cache()
    val matchTerm : String = "hello"
    val numMatches = inputFile.filter(line => line.contains(matchTerm)).count()
    println("%s lines in %s contain %s".format(numMatches, args(1), matchTerm))
    System.exit(0)
  }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<init>(ActorCell.scala:305)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<clinit>(ActorCell.scala)
    at akka.actor.RootActorPath.$div(ActorPath.scala:152)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:465)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:550)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:139)
    at spark.example.SparkGrep$.main(SparkGrep.scala:14)
    at spark.example.SparkGrep.main(SparkGrep.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What should I change in this simple code to make it run?

Comment: Which Scala version are you compiling against?

Comment: scala sdk 2.11.8,   jdk 1.6

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg switch to jdk 1.7 and see if that doesn't clear it up

Comment: Is your Spark compilied against 2.11.8? Because Spark out of the box compiles against 2.10.x

Comment: just switched to using jdk 1.8, but getting the same error

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg Try using Scala 2.10.x instead.

Comment: yep - switching to scala sdk 2.10.6 let me get passed that issue. will be happy to accept as the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather common mistake of forgetting Spark is compiled against an older version of Scala (2.10.x, as of Spark 1.6.1 (this is subject to change soon with Spark 2.0)).

Changing your code to compile with the said version should fix you runtime issue.

Answer (score 0):

**You can build Spark 1.6.1 with Scala 2.11.x** 
Using 
`./dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh` 
 or 
`./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11`

And after that 
`mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package`
For more information:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211