# Cloudant database not connecting using Spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudant

I am using Spark version 2.0.1 and trying to connect cloudant database using Python code but same time I am getting an error.

Error is throwing at "load(cloudant_credentials['db_name'])" so is there any library I am missing to import?

I am sure that I am using correct credentials of Cloudant.

I tried using Java code but getting same error.

Here is my Python code,

```
import pandas
import pyspark
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

#Needs to be created once.
sc = SparkContext("local[4]","demo")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
print(sc.version) //2.0.1

tic = timeit.default_timer()
candidate_data = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host",cloudant_credentials['url']).\
option("cloudant.username",cloudant_credentials['username']).\
option("cloudant.password",cloudant_credentials['password']).\
load(cloudant_credentials['db_name'])
toc = timeit.default_timer()
```

Dependencies I am using,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/resource/spark-cloudant-2.0.0-s_2.11.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId> <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId> 
            <version>2.6.2</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId> <artifactId>config</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalaj-http_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Below error I am getting,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-44e0613fa6f4> in <module>()
      6 print(cloudant_credentials['db_name'])
      7 
----> 8 candidate_data = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").option("cloudant.host",cloudant_credentials['url']).option("cloudant.username",cloudant_credentials['username']).option("cloudant.password",cloudant_credentials['password']).load(cloudant_credentials['db_name'])
      9 
     10 toc = timeit.default_timer()

/home/spark/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.pyc in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    145         self.options(**options)
    146         if isinstance(path, basestring):
--> 147             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    148         elif path is not None:
    149             if type(path) != list:

/home/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/spark/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o111.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.actorSystem()Lakka/actor/ActorSystem;
    at com.cloudant.spark.DefaultSource.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using cloudant package in spark-submit: https://spark-packages.org/package/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant

**Include this package in your Spark Applications using:
spark-shell, pyspark, or spark-submit**

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages cloudant-labs:spark-cloudant:2.0.0-s_2.11
```

---

Note: you can use also the following format from: 
https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant

see example here:
https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/blob/master/examples/python/CloudantDF.py

Comment: @CodeIdenti - ok, I guess that you are missing the cloudant-lab package, see my updated answer

Comment: still getting same error. Even I tried in java and getting same error is there any compatibility issue?

Comment: It seems spark-cloudant package is not loading while submit the spark job.. I think this is causing an issue.. I posted full of details over here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927252/submit-spark-job-is-not-loading-spark-cloudant2-0-0-s-2-11-package

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 2.0 we are using `SparkSession` instead of `SparkContext` and`SQLContext`. You can see an example here: https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/blob/master/examples/python/CloudantDF.py#L23-L30

Comment: getting same error while performing execution at df = spark.read.load("n_airportcodemapping", "com.cloudant.spark").. While using SparkSession

Comment: I think you have some incompatible settings between Spark and Scala versions. Check this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728795/how-to-overcome-scala-nosuchmethoderror, it may help you.  If you are using spark-cloudant 2.0, make sure you really have Scala 11 and Spark 2.0 compiled against Scala 11.

Comment: It seems spark-cloudant package is not loading while submit the spark job.. I think this is causing an issue.. I posted full of details over here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927252/submit-spark-job-is-not-loading-spark-cloudant2-0-0-s-2-11-package