# Submit Spark job is not loading spark-cloudant:2.0.0-s_2_11 package

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudant

I am submitting Spark using below command,

> ./spark-submit --packages cloudant-labs:spark-cloudant:2.0.0-s_2.11
>   --class spark.cloudant.connecter.cloudantconnecter --master local[*] /opt/demo/sparkScripts/ScoredJob/sparkcloudantconnecter.jar

But it seems "spark-cloudant" package is not loading..
Might be it is not loading because of artifact located at Spark Packages repository(https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/)

**So What changes is require in command to load the package?**

Full details of This package is showing here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/2.0.0-s_2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems require to add repository while loading package using Spark-submit command,

> -- repository url

So new command will be,

> ./spark-submit --packages cloudant-labs:spark-cloudant:2.0.0-s_2.11
>   **--repositories https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/** --class spark.cloudant.connecter.cloudantconnecter --master local[*]
>   /opt/demo/sparkScripts/ScoredJob/sparkcloudantconnecter.jar